# How can I make the ACR User Dialogs ShowLoading method run as an async task?

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms, async-await

Is it possible to run the ACR UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading method as an async Task? I tried the following, but the loading animation stutters, suggesting that it isn't running async:

```
await Task.Run(async () =>
{                
    UserDialogs.Instance.ShowLoading("doing stuff...");
});

await DoComplexStuff();
UserDialogs.Instance.HideLoading();
```

It would be preferable to run the ShowLoading method as an async Task as opposed to having to rewrite the DoComplexStuff method (and the many methods it calls).

Answer (score 2):

```cs
using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("doing stuff..."))
{
    await DoComplexStuff();
}
// no hide loading needed
```

Maybe your `DoComplexStuff` is running on the UI Thread. You could try to move it into a new thread:

```cs
using (UserDialogs.Instance.Loading("doing stuff..."))
{
    await Task.Run(DoComplexStuff);
}
```